# Safely move svn folders and files

Tags: shell, svn, ubuntu

I have a local folder `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/`, which contains several sub-folders, some of which may contain sub-folders and files..

`/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/` is a versioned resource. According to `svn info` under `/mnt/.../P/ct/`, `URL` is `https://.../mc/ct`.

A part of its sub-folders are NOT versioned, for instance:

`svn info` under `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/subfolder2/` returns `svn: '.' is not a working copy`

A part of its sub-folders are versioned, for instance:

`svn info` under `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/subfolder1/` shows its `URL` is `https://.../mc/ct/subfolder1`

In a versioned folder, NOT all the files are versioned.

Now, what I would like to do is to move everything under `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/` to `/mnt/.../oo/P/`, and delete `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/`. For instance, the previous `/mnt/.../oo/P/ct/subfolder1/` will become `/mnt/.../oo/P/subfolder1/`.

I want this action to move all the versioned and non-versioned folders & files, I want this action to do not impact the svn URL of each folder / file.

This folder is very important... Could anyone tell me how to do this transfer safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the folder and its child folders recursively with your OS command.

Then go look at it to see if everything moved and is still connected correctly to SVN. It should be but paranoia doesn't mean SVN isn't out to get you. Add a file and check it in. Delete it and see if all that works.

Then go delete the old folder and children.

Of course, this only works if there isn't a  nested `ct` folder inside `/oo/P/ct`

Answer (score 1):

svn revisions file systems, as such, you can't just stitch together two revision histories into one file system without a high risk of conflict.

This means that when you are dealing with one svn checkout (which is a whole tree), you can easily move stuff from branch (directory) to branch (directory); however, if you are checking out from a different repository, branch, etc. and trying to stitch things into a place where they don't reflect the repository's history, you need to strip one of the checkouts of it's SVN metadata.  To do that, after the checkout of the repository that is not going to receive the merged data, remove all it's `.svn` directories.  This makes them regular files, which can be added to the receiving repository.

I hope that those mountpoints implement POSIX file system properties (which things like nfs don't) because otherwise, you're going to discover bad stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your comment... What do you think of the solution of @Lee Meador? I think that makes sense...

Comment: I think Lee's solution might work, depending on if his idea of your setup is a correct representation of your setup.  There is no way to really get around it, you need to read the redbook.